# Query Optimization Suggestion

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose you have a query (PL-SQL) such as:

```
Select a.*
From Table a
Where a.foo in (@1) 
   or a.bar in (@1);
```

Where `@1` is a list containing about 10.000 (string) parameters. Yes, the list is repeated in both restrictions. And for any given row, `a.foo <> a.bar`.

This list comes from a webservice, and it changes according to a set of parameters. Suppose it is not possible to store them. The strings in this list are numeric strings, with 9 characters, such as '001234567'.

Is there a better way to structure this query?

Comment: if the strings were properly stored in a database table and with the appropriate indexes you  could use a join

Comment: What is "@"?  that is certainly not an oracle parameter.  Where do these "string parameters" come from?  Why can't you store in a table? First off, you cannot have an IN list with 10K parameters.  Max is 1000.  This really looks like a flawed design, and maybe you need to re-consider how to do it.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, I know I can't have an IN list with 10K parameters. I just made it simpler by putting it this way. @ is just a markup I used, also to make it simpler to identify a parameter. Under the hood, I am chopping this list in portions of 1000 elements and using (a.bar IN (...) OR a.bar IN (...))

Comment: @scaisEdge Unfortunately this is not the case. I get those strings via a webservice, and they change according to a lot of parameters.

Comment: Then please show some "real" code, and update question with specifics - example parameters string, etc.

Comment: @OldProgrammer not sure how it would help in this case. I get the parameters from a webservice, and they vary, so suppose it is not possible to store them. As for the strings, they are numeric strings, with 9 characters, such as '001234567'

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:210612357425

Comment: I dont understand the question. The simple answer is if you cannot store or join or index there is NO better way to do it.  Who upvoted this

Comment: Aren't there in-memory temporary tables in Oracle? One could create one for the current connection, fill it with the values of the current batch, perform a join and throw the table away.

Comment: The code shown is not valid PL/SQL (or SQL). Please [edit] your question and add the **complete** procedure

Comment: I suppose you could write a function that took `foo`, `bar`, and your `@1` array and returned something to indicate a match. It would probably be less efficient than plain SQL, but depending on your requirement that might not matter too much.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in your question (and comments) then the simple answer is no there is not a better way to structure your query, however there is almost certainly a better way to design this process so that you aren't forced to use the procedure to which this horrible pseudo-code snippet alludes.